# Django - Saving contents of a form into a database

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
class InitialForm(forms.Form):
    Teacher_Name = forms.CharField(label='Teacher Name')
    Subject = forms.CharField(label = 'Subject')
    Question = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the first question?')
    Topic = forms.CharField(label = 'What topic is this on?')
    Option1_Q = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the first option?')
    Option2_Q = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the second option?')
    Option3_Q = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the third option?')
    Option4_Q = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the fourth option?')
    Answer_Q = forms.CharField(label = 'Which option is the correct option?', widget=forms.Select(choices=Options))
```

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    testID = AutoSlugField(unique=True)
    teacherID = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studentID = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    Q = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Topic = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option1_Q = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option2_Q = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option3_Q = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option4_Q = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    AnswerQ = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

```
def teachertests(request):
    form = InitialForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InitialForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'teachertests.html', {'form':form})
```

Hey, pretty new to coding in general and wanted to save the contents of the form into the database and then display specific fields from the form, not sure what I had done wrong, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a form it is important to add the form.is_valid() since from what you see you did not indicate in your form if there are fields that are not mandatory with the require=False as long as it is not valid it will not be saved

```
def teachertests(request):
    form = InitialForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InitialForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           data_form = form.cleaned_data
           question = Question() 
           question.Option1_Q = data_form.get('Option1_Q')
           # ....... all fields form
           question.save()
    return render(request, 'teachertests.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Hey, tried that out and it says Exception Value: 
'InitialForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: @GuranshMadhan ok I see that you are using forms.Form so I recommend you do it in the following ways, I edit my answer